# Using CSS, is there a way that when I hover over one component, a different component becomes visible?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have an `<div id="icon">` tag and a `<div id="notif">` tag. When I hover over the `<i>` tag, I want the `<div id="notif">` tag's visibility to go from `hidden` to `visible`. Is there a way to do this using CSS `:hover`?

here is my HTML:

```
<br/>

<div id="icon">
    Hover over me!
</div>

<br/>
<br/>

<div id="notif">
    And you can see me!
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#icon:hover {
  
  
}

#notif{
  color: red;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

I'm not sure what to put into the `#icon:hover`! Any help would be great

Link JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/livmarx/L02r4jxt/4/

Comment: Try `#icon:hover ~ #notif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `~` selector to select sibling element.

Like so -

```css
#icon:hover ~ #notif {
  visibility: visible;
}

#notif{
  color: red;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="icon">
    Hover over me!
</div>

<br/>
<br/>

<div id="notif">
    And you can see me!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [General sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

```css
#notif {
  color: red;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#icon:hover ~ #notif {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<div id="icon">
  Hover over me!
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="notif">
  And you can see me!
</div>
```